# Automatically send an email from an app

Tags: java, android

My app is really progressing now, much of it due to you guys and your willingness to help out so thanks alot.
As to my problem, I want my app to email a user each day as a kind of reminder additional to notifications.  However I can't find a way to do this without user intervention, I am aware I can use a send intent but I want it to be automated without the user needing to do anything other then select the option in the settings to enable email reminders.
I don't actually know if this is even possible but I'm hoping that is.  If it isn't maybe there's a way i can hack it together to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap

Answer (score 4):

Doubt the app will be able to send an email itself, but what you should be doing anyway is sending this to a web server and then having a script on a server to send an email from example@yourdomain.com

Also worth noting that it would be a bit odd if the app emailed the user directly as the email would be addressed from the same person as it was sent to

Comment: I agree with @olly. And if your intent is to remind them of something with your app, why not use a notification? That would give them a better chance of seeing the reminder in a timely manner than sending an email.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the idea is i'm making a task app so every day the user will be emailed a list of tasks for that day for reference when they are away from their phone

Comment: Do you have any web development experience? Could be even better if you could make a site so that any user can access there tasks from anywhere. There are still people who don't use webmail